# When a function/method should ask for * or &

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

Edit: Thanks all. Lots of great info to go over. Will take me a while to absorb.

After 10+ years of an unhealthy romance with programming, I think I'm finally getting my head around pointers. But I'm still not comfortable with them.

I have some relatively simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class MyString
{
private:
    char* buffer;

public:
    //Constructor
    MyString(const char* initString)
    {
        if(initString != NULL)
        {
            buffer = new char[strlen(initString)+1];
            strcpy(buffer, initString);
        }
        else
            buffer = NULL;
    }
    //Destructor
    ~MyString()
    {
        cout << "Invoking destructor, clearing up\n";
        if (buffer != NULL)
            delete [] buffer;
    }

    int GetLength()
    {
        return strlen(buffer);
    }

    const char* GetString()
    {
        return buffer;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyString SayHello("Hello from String Class");
    cout << "String buffer in MyString is " << SayHello.GetLength();
    cout << " characters long\n";

    cout << "Buffer contains: " << SayHello.GetString() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does `MyString` wish to make a pointer from the first argument (in `main()`?) Why doesn't it just pass by copy? or use the address of operator?

Am I asking the 'wrong question'? Not seeing something clearly?

Many thanks. Hope the question is clear.

Comment: Unrelated, yet very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three/4172961

Comment: Arrays can't be passed by value. You either need to pass them by reference (but that usually requires templates) or use their implicit decay-into-pointer property to instead pass a pointer to the first element. Use a `std::array` wrapper instead if you want an array that has more intuitive value semantics.

Comment: In modern C++ pointers are used mostly for interop with C.

Comment: @VTT Even in modern c++ only projects you still use raw pointers at many place. You use them (or references) when you pass an object, but you don’t transphere its ownership. So basically for all utility functions you normally pass the raw pointer or a reference to the object that is managed by a smart pointer.

Comment: @t.niese *"you still use raw pointers at many place. You use them when when you pass an object, but you don’t transphere its owner ship"* - that is where references should be used (or optional reference for nullability). There could be no "or" when selecting between pointer and reference.

Comment: @VTT I prefer `gsl::observer<T*>` over `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>`

Comment: @Caleth Isn't it called `gsl::observer_ptr<T>`? I prefer to use third-party policy-based wrappers `t_Reference<T, policy::t_Optional, policy::t_Rebindable, policy::t_InvalidAccess<policy::t_Action::assert> ...`

Comment: @VTT probably, or just `T *`

Comment: Use `<cstring>` in C++, not `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

It does not.
String literals are just a sequence of characters somewhere in the memory. They are not wrapped by some object.
An object like `MyString` or `std::string` may act as a wrapper object and have a way to copy them or change them.
But a string literal is just memory. Sequence of characters that ends with `'\0'`. They cannot be changed so the way to access them is a `const char*`.

This is passing a string literal by `poiter` which is fairy fast.
You may accept `std::string` which has explicit constructor and will create an `std::string` string object from the string literal.

Passing by reference(&), on the other hand, is fairly different concept.
It is like passing the object. No copy, no pointer(it might be done with pointer by the compiler but you should not think about that).

Comment: `char[]` values are objects once temporary materialisation is done. They just aren't objects of *some class type*.

Comment: there are several questions in OPs post, and it is not 100% to which "It does not" refer to

Answer (score 1):

> Why does MyString wish to make a pointer from the first argument (in main()?)

Because arrays transform into pointers at the slightest provocation, and `""` literals are `const char` arrays.

> Why doesn't it just pass by copy?

Because you can't assign or copy a C-style array.

> or use the address of operator?

There is an implicit conversion from `const char[23]` to `const char *`.

Aside:

In c++, the null pointer is spelled `nullptr`, you can safely `delete[]` one, and there is an implicit copy constructor and copy assignment operator generated for `MyString`, which will lead to double `delete[]`s of `buffer`